# HTML CSS - Image Resizing

Tags: html, css

If I have an image - say 20*20 pixels

I can use this line to resize the image - it will make the entire image smaller:

```
 <img src="images/online-dating-main/blinking smile14x14.gif" width="14" height="14"/>
```

How can I do this resizing with CSS?

I have tried this but it just crops the image:

```
 <div id="smile"></div>

  div#smile {
     background: url(../images/online-dating-main/smile.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
     width: 14px;
     height: 14px;
 }
```

How can I do resizing with CSS?

thx

Comment: I never rely on the browser to do image re-sizing... depending on the browser it tends to look blurry or jagged.  If the image is much larger than your desired size, the full-size image must still download even though you're displaying it smaller.  I prefer to do image resizing in Photoshop and just display the full image at 100% scale in the browser.

Comment: it looks like you're using two separate images, which would explain the cropping. you don't need background clip or background size for that one. your css is correct. your image uri's don't match.

Comment: I used imageresize.php with two parameters width and height, you can upload one image and get multiple size dynamically, I also made a cache for repeated image sizes. (The file imagesize.php) is PHP script which can be used for image re-sizing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [`background-size: contain;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#Values) to the `div#smile` selector.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkEcH/).

Note that browser support may be an issue. IE < 9 does not support this property.

Comment: Or couldn't he just apply the side attributes directly to the img tag instead of using a background image?

Comment: @jdi: The OP could too. But I figured they wanted to do it with a `background-image`.

Comment: Yea I just assumed that was one way he was trying to accomplish it. Multiple ways to skin this cat! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the img instead of using a background image?

```
 <img class="resize" src="images/online-dating-main/blinking smile14x14.gif" />
```

CSS

```
.resize {
    width: 14x;
    heigh: 14px;
}
```